# How can I make custom page templates work on child theme?

Tags: templates, page-template, child-theme, template-hierarchy, parent-theme

I have created a page template called `concert.php` under `page-templates` directory with the following content:

```php
<?php 
   /* Template Name: Concert*/

   add_body_classes('page_concert'); /* Custom function that adds arguments to
                                        body class using body_class filter */

   get_header();

   ...

   get_footer();

?>
```

The template shows up in the page editor as expected, however when loading a page that uses this template the default `page.php` template is used instead.

I've read in some threads that for a child theme to properly load page templates it is necessery to have a proper `index.php`, `header.php` and `page.php`, which I do have set in my theme folder. Also, some people have pointed out that the existence of a `front-page.php` leads to home page not loading its set template, however deleting the file from parent theme didn't do much for me.

The use of `Template: theme-name` inside the theme's `style.css` has said to be problematic, as well. But without that line of code the child theme becomes a standalone theme.

How can I make my custom page template work in a child theme? Has anyone been through the same situation?

Comment: I was actually looking at the problem the wrong way. So, what actually happened is that I was trying to use a page template in my home page, however the parent theme had a ```front-page.php``` which lead to my template not being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I have deleted `front-page.php` from the parent theme once again and now it is working. For some odd reason it didn't work the first time. Maybe I had some other thing set up incorrectly as well.

If anyone can close this thread, please do so!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I see you've answered your own question, but the answer you provided seems dubious to me, so I'm going to post this anyway.

A child theme needs a few key elements to work: a style.css with header information (including `Template: parent-theme-name`), a functions.php file (where you can enqueue the parent theme's stylesheet), and activation of the child theme from the WordPress admin. [Learn more about child themes in the WordPress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Once you have your child theme activated, all files in the child theme will override templates in the parent theme with the same name. [Take a look at the template hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/) to better understand the names of these templates and how they take precedence.

Finally, let's talk about page templates. You have the right idea by calling the file `concert.php` since for custom page templates, the file name should not be prepended with `page-`. This is used for specific slug- or id-driven page templates. At the top of this file, you need to include `/* Template Name: Name of Template */`, just like you have already. This will appear in the page attributes under `Template`. After creating this file and storing it in the child theme, you must select this template from the drop-down list under page attributes for your new page. [More information on page templates in the WordPress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

I hope this helps!